# Cannot build C project by Eclipse when two c sources are in the project

Tags: c, eclipse, build, yocto, toolchain

I would like to build c project by Eclipse.
The codes are ok (like following) but link is not worked. So I cannot build them.If the contents of sub() is defined in sub.h, build works fine.

I often use Microsoft visual studio, but I am a begginer of eclipse and I could not set the linker option.

## What I want to do

How can I link and build devided c-sources by eclipse?
I want to build the project by just clicking  "Build All" button.

## Error message

- undefined reference to `sub'
- collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

## Eclipse setting

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- version: Eclipse Luna
- toolchain: Yocto toolchain (see http://variwiki.com/index.php?title=Yocto_Programming_with_Eclipse&release=RELEASE_MORTY_V1.0_DART-6UL)
- project property

[image]

## main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sub.h"

int main(void)
{
  printf("sub() = %d\n", sub());
  return 0;
}
```

## sub.c

```
#include "sub.h"

int sub(void)
{
  return 1;
}
```

## sub.h

```
#ifndef SUB_H
#define SUB_H

int sub(void);

#endif
```

Comment: You shouldn't define a global variable in a header file.

Comment: sorry this example code is not important. I do not use global var actually. The problem is link does not work fine. If I define sub() in sub.h and delete sub.c, build works fine. So I want to link them in eclipse option. However I cannot find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. This problem is special in the case of yocto development.

Adding sub.c in Makefile.am enabled to be built fine.

This link helped me.
https://community.nxp.com/docs/DOC-106613

Comment: No, it's not special in case of Yocto-development. If you're using autotools, you need to add all your sources in Makefile.am...

Comment: @Anders Thank you! Are there any eclipse option which can add all sources automatically in Makefile.am?

Comment: I'm not using Eclipse, so unfortunately, I can't help you.